# Project with path ':library' could not be found in root project 'application'

Tags: java, gradle, multi-module

Have a project structure with `gradle`:

```
- gs-multi-module
  - application
    - settings.gradle
  - library
    - settings.gradle
- settings.gradle
```

gs-multi-module - `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'gs-multi-module'

include 'library'
include 'application'
```

application - `settings.gradle`:

```
settings.gradle
```

library - `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'library'
```

Why do I get an error when I try to run the `application` component:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'application'.
> Project with path ':library' could not be found in root project 'application'.
```

I read the [Creating a multi-project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:creating_multi_project_builds) documentation and did everything according to the documentation.

[Spring Boot Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/).

[ScreenShot - Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBZV1.png)